# __VA_OPT__ not expanded in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have MSVS2019 19.29 and I would like to make use of `__VA_OPT__`, but when I run the preprocessor it seems to just replicate `__VA_OPT__(,)` without expanding.

My code is:

```
#define M(X, ...) X __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__
M(3) // expands to 3
M(3, 4) // expands to 3, 4
```

I compile with cl /TP /P opt.c /Zc:preprocessor
and in opt.i I just find

```
3 __VA_OPT__(,) 
3 __VA_OPT__(,) 4
```

Is there any trick to make this feature work?

It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/preprocessor-experimental-overview?view=msvc-170) my MSVS version should be new enough.

Comment: `/std:c++latest` perhaps? Or at least C++20.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah seems that does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__VA_OPT__` is a C++20 feature, so you need `/std:c++latest` or at least `/std:c++20` (in addition to `/Zc:preprocessor` you're already using).